# Cannot find where php5-fpm is stored in MacPorts

Tags: macos, macports, php

I installed php5 from macports. But i can't find php-fpm for start.
Look in /opt/local/sbin and /usr/sbin/

I used console command:

sudo port install php5

May be need some like php5 +fastcgi fscgi

Answer (score 1):

FPM support is still in the works at this writing; see [Trac ticket #26039](http://trac.macports.org/ticket/26039).

Comment: And now it looks like FPM support has been added since then. :-)